# How do I do a command like array.shift() to an XML string?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML like this stored in a String variable in JavaScript :

```
<metadata>
<a>...</a>
<b>...</b>
<c>...</c>
</metadata>

<data>
<a>...</a>
<b>...</b>
<c>...</c>
</data>
```

Since a valid XML can only have single root tag, mine cannot be called valid as it has two root tags: `metadata` & `data`. I would like to completely remove the `metadata` tag, as I don't have any use of it either.

I read about array.Shift() command, which removes the first element of an array. But since I have an XML, how do I do the same? Again, would just like to remove the `<metadata>` tag, so the result XML looks like this (given below).

```
<data>
<a>...</a>
<b>...</b>
<c>...</c>
</data>
```

Comment: Add `<root>` at the start and `</root>` at the end, parse the XML, then use the returned DOM to manipulate it (or extract only the node you're interested in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)

```js
const xmlString = `
<metadata>
  <a>...</a>
  <b>...</b>
  <c>...</c>
</metadata>
<data>
  <a>...</a>
  <b>...</b>
  <c>...</c>
</data>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc1 = parser.parseFromString(`<root>${xmlString}</root>`, "application/xml");
doc1.querySelector('metadata').remove()
console.log(doc1.documentElement.innerHTML)
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you talk about a string, just search for '<data>' and get the substring from that position to the end:

```js
let str = `
    <metadata>
      <a>...</a>
      <b>...</b>
      <c>...</c>
    </metadata>
    
    <data>
      <a>...</a>
      <b>...</b>
      <c>...</c>
    </data>
    `

let data = str.substring(str.search('<data>'))

console.log(data)
```

Or search for '</metadata>' plus two new line characters to find the start of :

```
let data = str.substring(str.search('</metadata>\n\n') + 13)
```